# Docker compose zookeeper java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, apache-zookeeper

I have a local application with kafka and zookeeper but when i run docker compose up in my arch linux desktop kafka show this error:

container log:

```
kafka_1                 | java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
kafka_1                 |       at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
kafka_1                 |       at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:777)
kafka_1                 |       at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:344)
kafka_1                 |       at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1290)
kafka_1                 | [main-SendThread(zookeeper:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server zookeeper/172.18.0.2:2181.
kafka_1                 | [main-SendThread(zookeeper:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - SASL config status: Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
kafka_1                 | [main-SendThread(zookeeper:2181)] WARN org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Session 0x0 for sever zookeeper/172.18.0.2:2181, Closing socket connection. Attempting reconnect except it is a SessionExpiredException.
```

docker compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
    ports:
      - '2181:2181'
    networks:
      - domper-network

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - '9092:9092'
      - '9094:9094'
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://:9092,OUTSIDE://:9094
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka:9092,OUTSIDE://host.docker.internal:9094
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
    extra_hosts:
      - 'host.docker.internal:172.17.0.1' #gateway do docker
    networks:
      - domper-network

  postgres:
    image: postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: Admin@2021!
      POSTGRES_DB: domper
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: password
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - postgres-domper-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - domper-network

  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: 'admin@admin.com.br'
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: 'Admin@2021!'
    ports:
      - 16543:80
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    networks:
      - domper-network

  api:
    build: ./
    restart: 'no'
    command: bash -c "npm i && npm run migration:run && npm run seed:run && npm run start:dev"
    ports:
      - 8888:8888
    env_file:
      - dev.env
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/api
      - /var/www/api/node_modules/
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - kafka
    networks:
      - domper-network
    # healthcheck:
    #   test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:8888/healthcheck"]
    #   interval: 60s
    #   timeout: 5s
    #   retries: 5

  notification-service:
    build: ../repoDomperNotification/
    restart: 'no'
    command: npm run start
    ports:
      - 8889:8889
    env_file:
      - dev.env
    volumes:
      - ../repoDomperNotification/:/var/www/notification
      - /var/www/notification/node_modules/
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    networks:
      - domper-network
    healthcheck:
      test: ['CMD', 'curl', '-f', 'http://localhost:8889/healthcheck']
      interval: 60s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5

volumes:
  postgres-domper-data:
    driver: local
networks:
  domper-network:
```

but in my windows desktop works and i don't know what this mean, I think it's some host configuration.

I've tried all the things I found on the internet and none of them worked.

log after @OneCricketeer (remove remove host.docker.internal and the extra_hosts) suggestion:

```
repodompercore-kafka-1                 | ===> Running preflight checks ... 
repodompercore-kafka-1                 | ===> Check if /var/lib/kafka/data is writable ...
repodompercore-kafka-1                 | ===> Check if Zookeeper is healthy ...
repodompercore-kafka-1                 | SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
repodompercore-kafka-1                 | SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.30.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
repodompercore-kafka-1                 | SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/slf4j-simple-1.7.30.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
repodompercore-kafka-1                 | SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
repodompercore-kafka-1                 | SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
repodompercore-kafka-1                 | log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (io.confluent.admin.utils.cli.ZookeeperReadyCommand).
repodompercore-kafka-1                 | log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
repodompercore-kafka-1                 | log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
repodompercore-kafka-1 exited with code 1
```

Comment: Can you share your docker compose file?

Comment: yes I  will put it in the post

Comment: I think you should remove `host.docker.internal` and the `extra_hosts` from the compose file.. Otherwise, assuming the kafka container does not die, you can exec into it and `ping zookeeper`

Comment: thanks for trying to help but it is still dying with a another log message, i update the post with the result